# Получить форму объекта имея ссылку (УП)

Tags: 1с

Изначально было всего 2 строчки:

```
ДокументОбъект = Получить объект по ссылке
ФормаДокумента = ДокументОбъект.ПоулчитьФОрму("ФормаДокумента");
```

И эту ересь в УП теперь на кучу строк нужно переписать.

В общих модулях имеется 2 функции, выполняемые - одна на сервере, другая на клиенте.

В функцию выполняющуюся на клиенте приходит ссылка документа (ссылка может быть всегда разной, т.к. разные документы используют функцию). Обращаюсь у серверу для получения по ссылке объекта. Далее - возвращаю структуру с свойствами обратно в функцию. Ссылка на объект имеется так же в структуре, т.к. есть необходимость потом изменить объект. По ссылке нужно так же получить форму на клиенте. Код:

```
&НаКлиенте
...
ДокументСтруктура = ВспомФункцииУФСервер.УстановитьСнятьОбработкаЗавершенаПолучитьОбъект(ДокументСсылка);
ПараметрыФормы = Новый Структура("Ключ", ДокументСтруктура.Ссылка);
ФормаДокумента = ПолучитьФорму("ФормаДокумента", ПараметрыФормы);
...



&НаСервере
Функция УстановитьСнятьОбработкаЗавершенаПолучитьОбъект(ДокументСсылка) Экспорт 
ДокументОбъект = ДокументСсылка.ПолучитьОбъект();
Структура = Новый Структура;
Структура.Вставить("Ссылка", ДокументОбъект.Ссылка);
Структура.Вставить("ОбработкаЗавершена", ДокументОбъект.ОбработкаЗавершена);
Возврат Структура;
КонецФункции
```

Не могу разобраться в получении формы по ссылке.

Answer (score 1):

```
 // просто открыть
 ОткрытьФорму("Документ.МойДокумент.ФормаОбъекта", Новый Структура("Ключ", СсылкаНаОбъект));

 // через получение формы
 Форма = ПолучитьФорму("Документ.МойДокумент.ФормаОбъекта", Новый Структура("Ключ", СсылкаНаОбъект));
 Форма.Открыть();
```

работает только на Клиенте. На Сервере какие формы? ))

Answer (score 0):

В управляемом приложении при создании формы объект (ДокументОбъект) преобразуется в ДанныеФормыСтруктура и уничтожается. Далее объект можно получить только преобразовав реквизит формы "Объект" в значение (метод РеквизитФормыВЗначение). Тогда получим снова ДокументОбъект. Который можно модифицировать и затем преобразовать обратно в реквизит формы (метод ЗначениеВРеквизитФормы). Если открыть форму по ссылке и отдельно от формы получить объект, модифицировать и записать, то в форме уже ничего изменить не получится, т.к. версия данных объекта формы будет не совпадать с версией объекта в БД. (почитайте про объектные блокировки 1С. https://infostart.ru/public/543218/)